# Reply Indicator in Apple Mail When Replied via Gmail Web Interface

Tags: gmail, imap, apple-mail

Is there a way to get Apple Mail to display the reply indicator on a message that was replied to via the Gmail Web UI?  It's set up to use IMAP, and when I reply to a message using an iPhone the reply indicator shows up in Apple Mail (and vice versa)... but when I reply via the Web UI, Apple Mail never displays the reply indicator.  Is there some tweak or hack to enable this?

Comment: Are your settings same as in [this article](http://www.zaphu.com/2008/04/22/guide-ideal-settings-for-apple-mail-and-gmail-imap-syncing/) ?

Comment: Essentially. There's some variation, but that's pretty much how it's configured. The fact that messages get marked as replied to when sent via the iPhone indicates that Gmail is tracking this and Apple Mail is picking it up... just not when sent via the web UI for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only indication to the problem that I can find is in [Reply status doesn't show up in Apple Mail](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=60cdc54a6418651a&hl=en), dating from one year ago :

> Gmail does not store the IMAP \Answered flag when you send from the
>   browser.
>
> (The flag is stored and maintained when it is set by your IMAP
>   program.)

This is also supported by the recent blog of [Notes on GMail’s IMAP support](http://blog.dave.cridland.net/?p=41).

This seems to indicate that the problem is in Gmail itself not correctly acting as an IMAP client, rather than in Apple mail.

If that's the case, then no tweak or hack will enable this indicator, until Gmail improves its handling of IMAP flags. Or you can still use the Gmail account, but through a standards-compliant client program such as Apple mail.

Comment: I was hoping that an answer that gave me a solution would pop up, but it looks like there isn't one for the time being.  Thanks for digging up the links, harrymc.